# In my drawing application when I add in other custom shapes none of the shapes draw to the canvas

Tags: javascript

In my drawing application when I add in other custom shapes none of the shapes draw to the canvas.I think the problem is within the drawShape function. I have tried removing the line shape and it works with just the square if statement if and the circle has the else. If anyone also knows how to change the brush sizes you'd be a big help!

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Drawing App</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<style>
setBackgroundImage("img1.jpeg");
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div id="drawingcontainer">
    <div class="text">
        JavaScript Drawing
    </div>
    <!-- this contains the various color choices -->
    <div id="options">
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#871de0');" class="purple" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#eb159d');" class="pink" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#c92626');" class="red" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#db551b');" class="orange" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#ddc41e');" class="yellow" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#76b80f');" class="green" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#1974b4');" class="blue" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#000');" class="black" value="" />
        <input type="submit" onclick="setColor('#FFF');" class="white" value="" />
        
    </div>
    <!-- this contains the various color choices -->
    
    <div id = "shapes">
    <input type="submit" onclick="setShape('square');" class="square" value="square" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="setShape('circle');" class="circle" value="circle" />
    <input type="submit" onclick="setShape('line');" class="line" value="line" />


    </div>
    
    <div id = "resetTheCanvas">
        <button onclick="resetCanvas()">Reset Here</button>
        </div>
    

        <div id = "brushsize">
            <input type="submit" onclick="setSize();" value="5px" />
            <input type="submit" onclick="setSize();" value="10px" />
            <input type="submit" onclick="setSize();" value="15px" />
          </div>
          
          
          <div id = "backgroundImage">
            <input type="file" id="fileInput" onchange="setBackgroundImage(event)" accept="image/*"/>
            <button onclick="clearBackgroundImage()">Clear Image</button>
        </div>


        <div id="background">
            <input type="submit" onclick="setBackgroundImage('img1.jpeg');" value="Change Background" />
            <input type="submit" onclick="setBackgroundImage('img2.jpeg');" value="Change Background" />
            <input type="submit" onclick="setBackgroundImage('img3.jpeg');" value="Change Background" />
          </div>



    <canvas width="770" height="400" id="drawing">
    </canvas>
    
    
</div>
<script src="raf.js"></script>


<script>

//wait till the window is loaded before performining
//the init() function
window.onload=init;

// declare canvas contexts here so they are global
var ctx, ctx2, canvas2;

//canvas width and height
var w;
var h;
//create a global variable for the drawing context

//Position for object on the canvas
var xPos = 0;
var yPos = 0;

//sprite width and height
var spriteH = 40;
var spriteW = 40;

//what shape are we drawing
var shape;

//mouse down will turn on drawState, mouse up will turn off drawState
var drawState = false;

//do all the set up stuff here

function init() {
    //get the existing canvas defined in HTML
    var canvas = document.getElementById("drawing");
    ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    //grab the canvas width and height
    w = canvas.width;
    h = canvas.height;
    
    //register mouse events to canvas
    canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",getMousePosition,false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", drawOn,false);
    canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", drawOff,false);
    
    //create another canvas element to hold the shape we want to draw
    canvas2 = document.createElement("canvas");
    canvas2.width = spriteH;
    canvas2.height = spriteH;
    
    //setup the canvas context
    ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
    ctx2.strokeStyle = "#000000"; //black
    ctx2.lineWidth = 1;
    
    //set the initial color to white
    setColor("#ffffff");
    
    //set the default shape to a square
    setShape('square');
    
    //draw the shape in canvas2
    drawShape();
    
    //this is the draw function that will be repeated using animation frames
    draw();
    
}

function draw() {
    //this is in raf.js
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
    
    //draw what ever is in canvas2 at xPos,yPos
    if (drawState)
        ctx.drawImage(canvas2,xPos,yPos);
}

//update the position of the drawing object to the mouse position
function getMousePosition(e) {
    //need to subtract the offsetLeft and offsetTop positions of the element
    xPos = e.clientX - getPosition(e.currentTarget).x - spriteW/2;
    //we need to offset the scrolling using pageYOffset 
    yPos = e.clientY - getPosition(e.currentTarget).y- spriteH/2 + window.pageYOffset;
    
    //for debugging
    //console.log(e.currentTarget);
    //console.log("x = "+ xPos + " y = " + yPos);
}

//Script for getting element position is from
//reference:http://www.kirupa.com/html5/get_element_position_using_javascript.htm
function getPosition(element) {
    var xPosition = 0;
    var yPosition = 0;
  
    while(element) {
        xPosition += (element.offsetLeft - element.scrollTop + element.clientLeft);
        yPosition += (element.offsetTop - element.scrollLeft + element.clientTop);
        element = element.offsetParent;
    }
    return { x: xPosition, y: yPosition };
}

//functions to turn drawing state on and off
function drawOn(e) {
    drawState = true;
}

function drawOff(e) {
    drawState = false;
}

function drawShape() {
    ctx2.clearRect(0,0,spriteH,spriteH);
    if (shape == 'square') 
        makeSquare();
    if (shape == 'circle') 
        makeCircle();

    else
        makeLine();
    
    
}

function makeSquare() {
    //draw an other in canvas2 using existing fill color
    ctx2.fillRect(0,0,spriteW,spriteH);
    ctx2.strokeRect(0,0,spriteW,spriteH);
    
}

function makeCircle() {
    //draw a circle in canvas2 using existing fill color
    ctx2.beginPath();
    ctx2.arc(spriteH/2,spriteH/2,spriteH/2-1,0,2*Math.PI);
    ctx2.stroke();
    ctx2.fill();    
}
///??

function makeLine() {
    context.beginPath();
    context.moveTo(spriteH, spriteW);
    context.lineTo(spriteH*3, spriteW*3);
    context.stroke();
  }


//  function drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2) {
 //   context.beginPath();
 //   context.moveTo(spriteH, y1);
 //   context.lineTo(x2, y2);
 //   context.stroke();
  //}
///??
// Change color
function setColor(c) {
    ctx2.fillStyle = c;
    //need to redraw the shape as well
    drawShape();

}

function setShape(s) {
    //remember the shape
    shape = s;
    drawShape();
}

function resetCanvas() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("drawing");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}


function setSize() {
  // code to change the brush size
if (value == '5px') 
spriteH*1.5
spriteW*1.5
if (value == '10px') 
spriteH*2
spriteW*2
if (value == '15px') 
spriteH*2.5
spriteW*2.5


}
</script>


<script>
    var canvas = document.getElementById("drawing");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    function setBackgroundImage(imgSrc) {
        var backgroundImg = new Image();
        backgroundImg.src = imgSrc;
        backgroundImg.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(backgroundImg, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }
    }
    </script>



</body>
</html>
```